# How com provide language neutral data types

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, com

I have been studing COM for a while now and i understand how COM can provide langugae neutral code through using well known binary interfaces, but what i don't get until now is how COM provide language neutrak data types so for example if the implementation language of COM component was wrtitten in C++ and the consumer of the COM component was written in Java and suppose that we have an interface function like that

`int sum(int x, int y)`

So integer objects in C++ is different than integer objects in Java ,so how COM implement neutral data types ?

Comment: Interface Definition Language - in other words, IDL types map to language types. [MIDL Predefined and Base Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367090(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: oky and what about user defined data types how we can do it?

Comment: You can declare enums and classes in the IDL interface, each type declared in the interface can be used also.

Comment: User defined types are just aggregates of other primitive types. Through mapping / marshalling, all types can play nicely in whatever platform.

Comment: Check out VARIANT for details.

Comment: There are two kinds of COM.  The original "pure" kind, interfaces derive from IUnknown.  Type choices are free, whatever a C or C++ compiler can swallow.  Ultimately relying on the fact that C/C++ compilers base their type choices on what works well on the processor.  Then there's the popular kind that every *likes* to use, a subset called COM Automation.  Which has a very restricted set of permitted types, VARIANT, BSTR and SAFEARRAY are the main ones.  Automation has been extraordinary successful, practically any language runtime on Windows supports it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COM defines what the types it supports are. So an int (VT_I4 for example) is a 4-byte integer type in little endian format. A language that wants to support COM and uses big endian (for example) would have to convert it to little endian first.

Strings are defined as length-prefixed character arrays, so a language that uses some other format...you guessed, has to convert to the COM string type.

Arrays are defined a complex SafeArray types, you want an array, you have to construct a Safearray to pass over the COM interface.

This is not much different from network programming - if you've ever seen the functions hton() and ntoh() which convert between the formats used by the client machine and the network format defined by whoever invented the data formats used by sockets, you'll see that a common format is very common.